# Sort y axis of a mixed % change in csv file, using matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I have csv data sheet with stock names, prices, open, close... and price change %.  I am trying to make a scatter plot to show the stock (x axis) and percent change (y axis) with the Percent change starting from low to high (also would like to skip to just whole numbers).  Not sure what to add to accomplish this.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('bmh')
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Imme21/WordCloud/main/StockData2.csv')

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20, 10
df.dropna(inplace = True)

x = df.Stock
y = df['price change %']

plt.xlabel('Stock', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Percent Change', fontsize=16)
plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.show()
```

[image: y-axis of current plot]

Comment: Either change your data from string to float by removing `%` and convert Or use [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Quang commented, you can remove the `%` and convert to `float`:

```py
y = df['price change %'].str.replace('%', '').astype(float)
```

[image: scatter with fixed y tick labels]

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed.